# Clean way to connect to services running on the same host as the Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a single node Kubernetes cluster, installed using k3s on bare metal. I also run some services on the host itself, outside the Kubernetes cluster. Currently I use the external IP address of the machine (192.168.200.4) to connect to these services from inside the Kubernetes network.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? What I want to avoid is having to reconfigure my Kubernetes pods if I decide to change the IP address of my host.

Possible magic I which existed: a Kubernetes service or IP that *automagically* points to my external IP (192.168.200.4) or a DNS name that points the node's external IP address.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @GeertPt,

With minikube's `host.minikube.internal` in mind I search around and found that CoreDNS has a DNS entry for each host it's running on. This only seems the case for K3S.

Checking

```
kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o yaml
```

reveals there is the following entry:

```
  NodeHosts: |
    192.168.200.4 my-hostname
```

So if the hostname doesn't change, I can use this instead of the IP.

Also, if you're running plain docker you can use `host.docker.internal` to access the host.

So to sum up:

- from minikube: `host.minikube.internal`
- from docker: `host.docker.internal`
- from k3s: `<hostname>`

Answer (score 2):

That's what ExternalName services are for (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: ${my-hostname}
  ports:
  - port: 80
```

Then you can access the service from withing kubernetes as `my-service.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local`.

See: https://livebook.manning.com/concept/kubernetes/external-service

> After the service is created, pods can connect to the external service
> through the external-service.default.svc.cluster.local domain name (or
> even external-service) instead of using the service’s actual FQDN.
> This hides the actual service name and its location from pods
> consuming the service, allowing you to modify the service definition
> and point it to a different service any time later, by only changing
> the externalName attribute or by changing the type back to ClusterIP
> and creating an Endpoints object for the service—either manually or by
> specifying a label selector on the service and having it created
> automatically.
>
> ExternalName services are implemented solely at the DNS level—a simple
> CNAME DNS record is created for the service. Therefore, clients
> connecting to the service will connect to the external service
> directly, bypassing the service proxy completely. For this reason,
> these types of services don’t even get a cluster IP.

This relies on using a resolvable hostname of your machine. On [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/) there's a DNS alias `host.minikube.internal` that is setup to resolve to an IP address that routes to your host machine, I don't know if k3s supports something similar.